# copy to vector giving segfault

Tags: c++

I am trying to copy the vector data from `sample` to `Y` as below

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<double > >sample;
std::map<std::string, std::vector<double > >::iterator it1=sample.begin(), end1=sample.end();
std::vector<double> Y;
```

and am using the following code:

```
 while (it1 != end1) {
  std::copy(it1->second.begin(), it1->second.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
++it1;
}
```

It prints the output ok, however when I replace the above std::copy block with the below, I get a segfault.

```
 while (it1 != end1) {
std::copy(it1->second.begin(), it1->second.end(), Y.end());
++it1;
}
```

I just want to copy the contents of it1->second to Y. Why is it not working and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Obviously, you want to insert objects into your vector. However, `std::copy()` merely takes the iterators passed and writes to them. The iterators obtained by the `begin()` and `end()` iterators don't do any insertion. What you want to use is something like this:

```
std::copy(it1->second.begin(), it1->second.end(), std::back_inserter(Y));
```

The `std::back_inserter()` function template is a factory function for an iterator using `push_back()` on its argument to append objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    // your code goes here
    vector<int> vec;
    vector<int> test;
    vec.push_back(1);
    //test.push_back(0);
    copy(vec.begin(),vec.begin()+1,test.begin());
    cout << *(test.begin());
    return 0;
}
```

**output:
Runtime error    time: 0 memory: 3424 signal:11**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    // your code goes here
    vector<int> vec;
    vector<int> test;
    vec.push_back(1);
    test.push_back(0);
    copy(vec.begin(),vec.begin()+1,test.begin());
    cout << *(test.begin());
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**
**Success    time: 0 memory: 3428 signal:0**

**1**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    // your code goes here
    vector<int> vec;
    vector<int> test(5);
    vec.push_back(1);
    //test.push_back(0);
    copy(vec.begin(),vec.begin()+1,test.begin());
    cout << *(test.begin());
    return 0;
}
```

**Success    time: 0 memory: 3428 signal:0**

**1**

SO the reason is that you didn't initilize the vector,the vector.begin() point to somewhere restricted!
when you use a back_inserter(vector) it return a back_insert_interator that internally use a
vector.push_back rather than a *(deference) operation. So back_inserter works!

Comment: Good catch. Thinking about it it makes sense that an empty iterator range can not be dereferenced.